# Angular two-way-binding with sub elements

Tags: checkbox, angularjs, model-binding, angularjs-directive

my problem is with creating an angular directive.

I want to create a group of checkboxes with just one single ng-model. It's like a bitfield or flags, i.e. the checkboxes have values from 0, 1, 2, 3 up to n but for ng-model I just want to add 2^value of all checked checkboxes. The values to add are then 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...

I wonder if there is a better, more correct or just simpler solution to my problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9h7EkEpDohXTniIDHdc5

In the example you can change the value in the textbox and the checks will be updated, but not the other way. It's a bit crazy, the code is working on my dev machine, but not in Plnkr!

```
app.directive('ngCheckboxFlags', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
        var flagSum;
        var checkboxes = [];

        // trigger changes of the ngModel
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (value) {
            flagSum = value;
            for (var i = 0, ii = checkboxes.length; i < ii; ++i) {
                var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
                checkbox.checked = flagSum & (1<<checkbox.value);
            }
        });

        for (var i = 0, inputs = element.find('input[type=checkbox]'), ii = inputs.length; i < ii; ++i) 
        {
            var checkbox = inputs[i];
            checkboxes.push(checkbox);
            // trigger changes of HTML elements
            $(checkbox).bind('change', function () {
                flagSum = ctrls.$viewValue ^ (1<<this.value);
                console.log(flagSum);

                //ERROR: Change not happening, textbox shows old value
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrls.$setViewValue(flagSum);
                });
            });
        }
    }
};
});
```

thnx in advance
knut

Comment: Well, your plunker wasn't working because you were binding directly to the scope level. Always bind to an object property (of an object on the scope). See this to understand what I mean: http://plnkr.co/edit/jgoMWDssothUlSy1oelP?p=preview . As for your actual question, "is there a better way?", I'm not that much of an expert so I'd say just stick to what works for now.

Comment: Funny! Exactly this was why it was correct in my dev machine (there I've a complex object) and not working on plnkr. Just wanted to simplify the code for my question and therefore used a primitive type. Better not to do in the future :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't bind the `ng-model` directly to primitive types, use an object instead:

```
$scope.sum = {
  ofCheckValues: 3
};
```

And on the HTML:

```
ng-model="sum.ofCheckValues"
```

*“Whenever you have ng-model there’s gotta be a dot in there somewhere. If you don’t have a dot, you’re doing it wrong.”*

**plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/NRAk3kyP1rdDmYrsz6ZL?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the tipp. As mentioned above (in the comment) this was why it was ok in my dev machine. But I'm still not sure if my solution is the good way for angular or if there is a more "angular way".

Answer (score 1):

Found a more elegant and shorter way: http://plnkr.co/edit/9h7EkEpDohXTniIDHdc5

My problem was

- didn't realize, that link() is called for each element
- therefore everytime a new 'scope' is created (for each element)
- I just have to stored a reference to the actual element in my variable (now called checkbox; was an array in the first version) for updating it, when the model changes (scope.$watch)
- I do not need a "global" flagSum, just a lokal one in the checkbox-binding for transfering the value to scope.$apply

  ```
  app.directive('ngCheckboxFlags', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
          var checkbox = element.find('input[type=checkbox]')[0];
          if (typeof checkbox === "undefined")
            return;

          // trigger changes of the ngModel
          scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (value) {
              checkbox.checked = value & (1<<checkbox.value);
          });

          $(checkbox).bind('change',  function () {
              var flagSum = ctrls.$viewValue ^ (1<<this.value);

              scope.$apply(function () {
                  ctrls.$setViewValue(flagSum);
              });
          });
      }
    };
  });
  ```

Comment: Just want to say this really helped me with a very similar problem, so thanks for posting.