# ng-include : How can I maintain data in $scope after changing views?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Please check this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mystikacid/b7hqcdfk/4/

Template:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="dataCtrl">

    <div>Data : {{data}} (Value outside views)</div>
    <div ng-include src="view"></div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="view1">
        <p> View 1 </p>
        <p>Value inside view 1 : {{data}}</p>
        <input type = "text" ng-model = "data" /> 
        <button ng-click = 'changeView("view2")' > Go to view 2 </button>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="view2">
        <p> View 2 </p>
        <p>Value inside view 2 : {{data}}</p >
        <input type = "text" ng-model = "data" />  
        <button ng-click = 'changeView("view1")' > Go to view 1 </button>
    </script>

</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('myFactory', function () {

    var factory = {};
    factory.data = 'Default data';

    return factory;
});

myApp.controller('dataCtrl', function ($scope, myFactory) {

    $scope.view = 'view1';
    $scope.data = myFactory.data;


    $scope.changeView = function (view) {
        $scope.view = view;
    }
});
```

There are two issues :

1 . Why does the data displayed outside views does not change on entering text?
 2 . If I enter some text and go to view 2, why does the data in the input box and view2 get reset ?

Please help me understand this behaviour, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding directly to primitive types (in your case a String). That doesn't work well in AngularJS... check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15134671);

Use a model object instead:

```
 myApp.factory('myFactory', function () {
     var factory = {};
     factory.model = {
         data: 'Default data'
     };

     return factory;
 });

 myApp.controller('dataCtrl', function ($scope, myFactory) {
     ...
     $scope.model = myFactory.model;
     ...
 });
```

And on the views:

```
<input type = "text" ng-model = "model.data" />
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uch9dncs/)